# Make Truffle deploy a contract and pass it as an argument to another contract's constructor

Tags: contract-development, truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

I have two contracts, `contractA` & `contractB`. I want Truffle to first deploy `contractA`, then pass it as an argument to `contractB`'s constructor.

This is what I am currently trying, but `contractB` never actually gets deployed:

```
let contractA = artifacts.require("./contractA.sol");
let contractB = artifacts.require("./contractB.sol");

module.exports = async function(deployer, network) {
  await deployer.deploy(contractA);  // this gets deployed fine
  deployer.deploy(contractB, contractA.address); // this *never* gets deployed
};
```

As a matter of fact, `contractB` does **not** get deployed even if I change the code to this:

```
await deployer.deploy(contractA);    
deployer.deploy(contractB, "0x123");  // does not deploy even if I enter the address manually
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this by creating multiple Truffle deployment files.

2_deploy_contractA.js:

```
// 2_deploy_contractA.js

let contractA = artifacts.require("./contractA.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer, network) {
    deployer.deploy(contractA);
};
```

3_deploy_contractB.js:

```
// 3_deploy_contractB.js

let contractA = artifacts.require("./contractA.sol");
let contractB = artifacts.require("./contractB.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer, network) {
    deployer.deploy(contractB, contractA.address);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
deployer.then(async function() {
    let contractA = await artifacts.require("A").new();
    let contractB = await artifacts.require("B").new(contractA._address);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Console logging `contractA` gives `undefined`.

Comment: Well, is your contract really saved in a file named `"A.sol"`? I wrote this as an example, I cannot guess your file names, so I used the same abbreviations as in your question.

Comment: Yes, it's `A.sol`

Comment: Well maybe change it to `"A.sol"`. That's how I usually do it (I just thought it was allowed without it, as recommended in Truffle official docs).

Comment: Yes already tried that as well.

Comment: When you run `truffle compile`, do you get an file named `A.json` in the artifacts folder?

Comment: Yes, the json file is generated. I just updated my question with my current state.